# My question is about R: How to number each repetition in a table in R?

Tags: r

In my data set, their is  column of full names (eg: below) and I want to add the another column next to it mentioning if a name has appeared two one, two, three, four.... times using R. My output should look like the column below: Number of repetition.

Eg: Data set name: People

```
**Full name**   **Number of repetition**
Peter   1
Peter   2
Alison  
Warren  
Jack    1
Jack    2
Jack    3
Jack    4
Susan   1
Susan   2
Henry   1
Walison 
Tinder  1
Peter   3
Henry   2
Tinder  2
Thanks 
Teena
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way solved with help from akrun: [sum() condition in ifelse statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69473273/sum-condition-in-ifelse-statement/69473281?noredirect=1#comment122795115_69473281)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Fullname) %>% 
  mutate(newcol = row_number(), 
         newcol = if(sum(newcol)> 1) newcol else NA) %>%
  ungroup
```

```
   Fullname newcol
   <chr>     <int>
 1 Peter         1
 2 Peter         2
 3 Alison       NA
 4 Warren       NA
 5 Jack          1
 6 Jack          2
 7 Jack          3
 8 Jack          4
 9 Susan         1
10 Susan         2
11 Henry         1
12 Walison      NA
13 Tinder        1
14 Peter         3
15 Henry         2
16 Tinder        2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.  Do a  group by 'Fullname', and create the sequence with `row_number()` if the number of rows is greater than 1.  By default, `case_when` returns the other case as `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   group_by(Fullname) %>%
   mutate(Number_of_repetition = case_when(n() > 1 ~ row_number())) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 16 × 2
   Fullname Number_of_repetition
   <chr>                   <int>
 1 Peter                       1
 2 Peter                       2
 3 Alison                     NA
 4 Warren                     NA
 5 Jack                        1
 6 Jack                        2
 7 Jack                        3
 8 Jack                        4
 9 Susan                       1
10 Susan                       2
11 Henry                       1
12 Walison                    NA
13 Tinder                      1
14 Peter                       3
15 Henry                       2
16 Tinder                      2
```

---

If we need to add a third column, use `unite` on the updated data from previous step

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   unite(FullNameRep, Fullname, Number_of_repetition, sep="", na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 3
   FullNameRep Fullname Number_of_repetition
   <chr>       <chr>                   <int>
 1 Peter1      Peter                       1
 2 Peter2      Peter                       2
 3 Alison      Alison                     NA
 4 Warren      Warren                     NA
 5 Jack1       Jack                        1
 6 Jack2       Jack                        2
 7 Jack3       Jack                        3
 8 Jack4       Jack                        4
 9 Susan1      Susan                       1
10 Susan2      Susan                       2
11 Henry1      Henry                       1
12 Walison     Walison                    NA
13 Tinder1     Tinder                      1
14 Peter3      Peter                       3
15 Henry2      Henry                       2
16 Tinder2     Tinder                      2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Fullname = c("Peter", "Peter", "Alison", "Warren", 
"Jack", "Jack", "Jack", "Jack", "Susan", "Susan", "Henry", "Walison", 
"Tinder", "Peter", "Henry", "Tinder")), row.names = c(NA, -16L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful Arun, you are a star, I have another question based on the same data set, If you could please help me that would be very helpful. I have to combine both the columns into third one, but only the ones which have number against them , not NA. So, if Alison has NA,then in the third column it should only say Alison, but for Peter, its should say, Peter1, Peter2....and so on.