# sum() condition in ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, sum

This question is related to this question [My question is about R: How to number each repetition in a table in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69472697/my-question-is-about-r-how-to-number-each-repetition-in-a-table-in-r#69472729)

Where basically the repetitions are numbered. E.g two repetitions: 1,2 ; three repetitions: 1,2,3 etc... But if the value is unique (only one time) it should have not `1` but `NA`

data: (from akrun, many thanks!)

```
df1 <- structure(list(Fullname = c("Peter", "Peter", "Alison", "Warren", 
                                   "Jack", "Jack", "Jack", "Jack", "Susan", "Susan", "Henry", "Walison", 
                                   "Tinder", "Peter", "Henry", "Tinder")), row.names = c(NA, -16L
                                   ), class = "data.frame")
```

my solution would be this:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Fullname) %>% 
  mutate(newcol = seq_along(Fullname)) 

  Fullname newcol
   <chr>     <int>
 1 Peter         1
 2 Peter         2
 3 Alison        1
 4 Warren        1
 5 Jack          1
 6 Jack          2
 7 Jack          3
 8 Jack          4
 9 Susan         1
10 Susan         2
11 Henry         1
12 Walison       1
13 Tinder        1
14 Peter         3
15 Henry         2
16 Tinder        2
```

Now I try to set each value that occurs once (e.g. Alison, Warren and Henry) to `NA`like akrun did here [My question is about R: How to number each repetition in a table in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69472697/my-question-is-about-r-how-to-number-each-repetition-in-a-table-in-r#69472729)

My code is with a `ifelse` statement checking if the sum of the group is >1.

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Fullname) %>% 
  mutate(newcol = seq_along(Fullname)) %>% 
  mutate(newcol = ifelse(sum(newcol)>1, newcol, NA))
```

but I get:

```
 Fullname newcol
   <chr>     <int>
 1 Peter         1
 2 Peter         1
 3 Alison       NA
 4 Warren       NA
 5 Jack          1
 6 Jack          1
 7 Jack          1
 8 Jack          1
 9 Susan         1
10 Susan         1
11 Henry         1
12 Walison      NA
13 Tinder        1
14 Peter         1
15 Henry         1
16 Tinder        1
```

**And I can't grasp why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `if/else` here instead of `ifelse` as `ifelse` requires all arguments to be same length, `sum` returns a single value and if it is `TRUE`, then all becomes TRUE

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Fullname) %>% 
  mutate(newcol = row_number(), 
       newcol = if(sum(newcol)> 1) newcol else NA) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 2
   Fullname newcol
   <chr>     <int>
 1 Peter         1
 2 Peter         2
 3 Alison       NA
 4 Warren       NA
 5 Jack          1
 6 Jack          2
 7 Jack          3
 8 Jack          4
 9 Susan         1
10 Susan         2
11 Henry         1
12 Walison      NA
13 Tinder        1
14 Peter         3
15 Henry         2
16 Tinder        2
```

---

Now, we look at the issue.  The 'newcol2' values are recycled values of single TRUE/FALSE.  In the `ifelse`, as all arguments need to be same length, the logical part is just of length 1.

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Fullname) %>% 
   mutate(newcol = row_number(), newcol2 = sum(newcol) > 1)
# A tibble: 16 × 3
# Groups:   Fullname [8]
   Fullname newcol newcol2
   <chr>     <int> <lgl>  
 1 Peter         1 TRUE   
 2 Peter         2 TRUE   
 3 Alison        1 FALSE  
 4 Warren        1 FALSE  
 5 Jack          1 TRUE   
 6 Jack          2 TRUE   
 7 Jack          3 TRUE   
 8 Jack          4 TRUE   
 9 Susan         1 TRUE   
10 Susan         2 TRUE   
11 Henry         1 TRUE   
12 Walison       1 FALSE  
13 Tinder        1 TRUE   
14 Peter         3 TRUE   
15 Henry         2 TRUE   
16 Tinder        2 TRUE
```

The way to tackle is `rep`licate to make the lengths same

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Fullname) %>% 
  mutate(newcol = seq_along(Fullname)) %>% 
  mutate(newcol = ifelse(rep(sum(newcol)>1, n()), newcol, NA))
# A tibble: 16 × 2
# Groups:   Fullname [8]
   Fullname newcol
   <chr>     <int>
 1 Peter         1
 2 Peter         2
 3 Alison       NA
 4 Warren       NA
 5 Jack          1
 6 Jack          2
 7 Jack          3
 8 Jack          4
 9 Susan         1
10 Susan         2
11 Henry         1
12 Walison      NA
13 Tinder        1
14 Peter         3
15 Henry         2
16 Tinder        2
```

---

In order to understand it better, just take a simple vector

```
> v1 <- c(1:5)
> sum(v1) > 4
[1] TRUE
> ifelse(sum(v1) > 4, v1, NA)
[1] 1
```

The `sum` here is 15 and it is definitely greater than 4.  As soon as the `TRUE` is found, it just returns the first element of the vector i.e. 1 and stops.  In the `%>%` also, this is what is happening, but because there is recycling, the 1 gets repeated to fill the whole group

Comment: @TarJae I added some eplanation. Hope it helps

Comment: This helps indeed. You just closed one more gap in my understand of programming an R!

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have already understood why the error occurs. I however, think `sum` is not the right function to use here. Yes, you can make it work but it seems convoluted. You can use `n()` to get number of rows in the group and check it with an `if` condition.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Fullname) %>%
  mutate(newcol = if(n() == 1) NA else row_number()) %>%
  ungroup

# Fullname newcol
#   <chr>     <int>
# 1 Peter         1
# 2 Peter         2
# 3 Alison       NA
# 4 Warren       NA
# 5 Jack          1
# 6 Jack          2
# 7 Jack          3
# 8 Jack          4
# 9 Susan         1
#10 Susan         2
#11 Henry         1
#12 Walison      NA
#13 Tinder        1
#14 Peter         3
#15 Henry         2
#16 Tinder        2
```